# Plot the tangent to a curve knowing the slope and a point

Tags: calculus

I am writing a computer program in javascript to help cement what I have learned so far about calculus, you can see what I have so far [here](http://www.d3geometry.com/functions).

What I want to add functionality that will display the tangent to the curve at any point on the curve where the user hovers the mouse over the curve.

For example, if the user hovers the point over the point (5, 9).  I want to show the tangent of the curve at that point.

If I was doing this with pen and paper, I would first of all find out the derivative which is ${2x}$ in this case which would make the gradient 10.

I would then construct the equation of the line:

${y - y1 = m(x — x1)}$ using the point.

I don't know what to do after that, how do I get my range of values for $x$ to plug into the equation to get my y values?

Comment: Is it a viewing window issue: making sure you take up exactly the right amount of space (line doesn't suddenly stop, nor expand the window)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of a linear function can look like this:

$$y = a*x+b \tag{1}$$

With the gradient you got already $a$ the only thing else that you need is the intersection with the y-axis which is contained in b.

Then by simply inserting your starting point (5,9) you get

$$ 9 = 10*5+b $$

Solving this for b gives:

$$ b = 9-50 = -41 $$

Or in general:

$$ b = y-a*x \tag{2} $$

The range of x should be as wide as you want to plot the tangent, most likely the same as the range of the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

You know everything you need to plot the derivate:

- $f'(x)$ (the derivative of the function $f(x)$)
- a point in which the derivative pass, namely $(m, f(m))$, where $m$ is the position of the pointer of the user

Then the line you have to draw is
$$y = f'(m)(x-m)+f(m) = x\cdot f'(m) + \left( f'(m) + f(m) \right)$$